# Set DataContext to entire window or ItemSource to individual control

Tags: wpf

What is preferable?

```
dataGrid1.ItemsSource = data;
```

Or:

```
public MainWindow()
....
this.DataContext = data;
....

<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion that depends on the design you are using.

If you're using the MVVM pattern there's no doubt about it: You'll always use your ViewModel as the DataContext of your View.

In cases where you just want to bind a list to a ItemsSource without using MVVM I would prefer your first case.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the case.

If you have two Grids in your application and each one needs its own different datasource. Setting on the MainWindow won't help.